# How to get the bitness of Microsoft Office from the registry?

Tags: microsoft-outlook, powershell, windows-registry

How is it possible to get the value of the registry storing data on the bitness of the Microsoft office, to be precise, the Outlook.
I found the location of the bitness in the registry and tried to get it into a variable with the `Get-ItemPropertyValue` command

```
$srp = Get-ItemPropertyValue -Path HKCU:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Office\16.0\Outlook -Name Bitness
```

But due to the fact that `Bitness` is of type `reg_sz`, I get the error

> Get-ItemPropertyValue: Bitness property does not exist in the path.

Please tell me how can I get the value in order to compare it later?

Comment: it's in `HKLM:`, not `HKCU:`. if you change that, your command works

Comment: Agree with SimonS, I can get the bitness of outlook from the registry through the modified instruction(Get-ItemPropertyValue -Path HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Office\16.0\Outlook -Name Bitness). It is recommended that you could write the correct instruction as answer for marking.

Comment: Hi MPP, I am writing to see if there is any progress on the issue. If this issue is resolved now, would you mind marking the helpful post as an answer? Which would benefit others who also has similar issues in forum.

Answer (score 1):

For click-to-run versions you can check another registry path.

```
$version = Get-ItemPropertyValue -Path HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Office\ClickToRun\Configuration -Name platform

if($version -eq 'x86'){
    Write-Host The version of office installed is 32 bit.
}
elseif($version -eq 'x64'){
    Write-Host The version of office installed is 64 bit.
}
```

As you see it's named `platform` and it returns either `x86` or `x64`